Play Store Verification Rejection
We are facing an issue with Play Store Profile verification and would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve it.
Background:

Initially, our account was created as an individual account.
We later shifted it to an organization account and began the verification process.
The Proof of organisation document was completed successfully without any issues.
However, when we submit our organization PAN card, the profile verification keeps getting rejected with the error:
"The document type that you submitted is not supported."

Details:

We are submitting a valid organization PAN card for verification in JPEG format.
The rejection only happens in the PAN card verification process verification process, while the Proof of organisation document went through successfully.




Questions:

Has anyone else faced this issue when transitioning from an individual to an organization account?
Are there specific requirements or document formats for submitting an organization PAN card that we might be missing?
Could this be related to a mismatch between individual and organization profile types during the transition?

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

try to go back to the first step of the verification and re submit everything

already tried that thing but it's not working, anything else to try without risking account?

I don't know, maybe try an ID card if not already tested

@Wawa we are already using PAN Card of company which is government authorized card and playstore is asking for the same card still i don't know what's the issue here... can it be related to format of file? like we are uploading JPEG instead of PDF so should we try with PDF for the same?

After proof of organization document, you need to upload the individual PAN card for verification, not the company's.

even for organization account?
